# Excluding 0 from Brainerd-Robinson similarity

Tags: r, similarity

I am using the following method from [Daniel Weidele](https://gist.github.com/dweidele/10561e02e5b189161a5c) to calculate a Brainerd-Robinson similarity for a set of data (code below). My rows represent places and my columns represent ages of people found at each place. I am using similarity to measure which places have similar demographic compositions to each other, and then I am using the output in a network analysis.

My problem is that lots of my places have '0' people in certain age categories, and so the similarity index shows strong links between these places. I would like to run two iterations of the model, both i) where the '0's are accounted for and ii) where '0' are ignored, i.e. so I just return indices generated on positive data.

I have tried various methods of excluding '0' from the analysis and nothing has worked so far. Any suggestions for this? Thanks.

```html
# function to load the observations
load = function() {
  p <- read.csv("observations.csv")  
  rownames(p) <- p[,1]
  p <- p[,c(2:6)]
  return(p)
}

# function to compute the normalized Brainerd-Robinson similarity for observations x
BR <- function(x) 
{
  rd <- dim(x)[1]
  results <- matrix(0,rd,rd)
  for (s1 in 1:rd) {
    for (s2 in 1:rd) {
      results[s1,s2] <- 1 - (sum(abs(x[s1, ] / sum(x[s1,]) - x[s2, ] / sum(x[s2,]))))/2
    }
  }
  rownames(results) <- rownames(x)
  colnames(results) <- rownames(x)
  return(results)
}

# load observations, compute Brainerd-Robinson similarity and write results to file
write.csv(BR(load()), "br.csv")
```

Comment: Would it make sense for your data, to input an average across all ages in places of 0?

Comment: I would then have the same problem, wouldn't I? If all 0 are replaced with the same n, then these values will still be marked as 100% 'similar'?

Comment: If I were to replace all of my '0' with NA, would there be a neat way to exclude them from the analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to ask the author directly? :)

When you look at the line

```
results[s1,s2] <- 1 - (sum(abs(x[s1, ] / sum(x[s1,]) - x[s2, ] / sum(x[s2,]))))/2
```

this is mostly where the magic happens. Let me outline what is going on here, just looking at the right side of the assignment operation `<-`:

```
1 - (sum(abs(x[s1, ] / sum(x[s1,]) - x[s2, ] / sum(x[s2,]))))/2
```

Let us call

- the vector `x[s1,]` the *Obvserations Of Site 1* (**OOS1**),
- the number (or scalar) `sum(x[s1,])`, which is then `sum(OOS1)` the *Sum of Site 1* (**SOS1**),
- and the vector `x[s1,] / sum(x[s1,])` the *Normalized Observations of Site 1* (**NOS1**)

We can then rewrite our right-hand part of the assignment to:

```
1 - (sum(abs(OOS1 / SOS1 - OOS2 / SOS2)))/2
```

or

```
1 - (sum(abs(NOS1 - NOS2)))/2
```

The important part is, that NOS1 and NOS2 are still vectors containing the numbers of observed values per category, just normalized to the proportion in the site.

Now the crucial part for your question: `abs(NOS1 - NOS2)`.

```
NOS1 - NOS2
```

simply subtracts one vector from the other. This is where you want to make your modification, in order to not account for 0 values:

```
differenceIgnoreZeroes <- function(u, v) 
{
  # input vectors u and v should have equal length for this to work
  result <- vector()
  for (i in 1:length(u)) {
    if(u[i] == 0 || v[i] == 0) next # SKIP IF EITHER VALUE IS 0
    result[i] <- u[i] - v[i]    
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Having this function defined we thus write `differenceIgnoreZeroes(NOS1, NOS2)` rather than `NOS1-NOS2`.

We next continue taking the absolute value as before:

```
abs(differenceIgnoreZeroes(NOS1, NOS2))
```

As the resulting vector now contains 'NA' values, when summing over the vector we need to be careful to not account for these `NA`s, otherwise the whole sum would become `NA`, too. Therefore set a parameter *na.rm* to T(rue):

```
sum(abs(differenceIgnoreZeroes(NOS1,NOS2)), na.rm = T)
```

Thus, our total right-hand assignment looks like the following:

```
1 - (sum(abs(differenceIgnoreZeroes(OOS1 / SOS1, OOS2 / SOS2)), na.rm = T))/2
```

which further expands to

```
1 - (sum(abs(differenceIgnoreZeroes(x[s1, ] / sum(x[s1,]), 
x[s2, ] / sum(x[s2,]))), na.rm = T))/2
```

I hope this helps!

Cheers,

Daniel Weidele